# TWAIN SANE Interface and Image Capture in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, twain, scanning, sane

My scanner won't show under Devices in Mac OS X Image Capture. 
I have installed the necessary files for TWAIN SANE Interface as mentioned here http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/.

I was able to scan via scanimage in terminal and I am currently looking for a TWAIN Application that supports SANE in Mac OS X so that I can scan via NETWORK.

Comment: You can try Dynamic Web TWAIN online demo

Comment: @yushulx : my scanner was not detected :(

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: One can downloaded demo (30 day trail) from https://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner.aspx

It worked perfectly.